# What is the use of Django setting the ETag header?

Tags: python, django, etag

What is the ETag header, why does Django set it and how should I use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> An ETag, or entity tag, is part of HTTP, the protocol for the World Wide Web. It is one of several mechanisms that HTTP provides for cache validation, and which allows a client to make conditional requests.

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag).

Basically, you do a md5 or something of the file, and if the file changes, the ETags do not match and the browser can download a new copy.

Comment: Additionally, here are the Django docs for working with ETags: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/conditional-view-processing/